# How to loop rows in dynamically generated table

Tags: jquery, loops

i am working on adding various insurance policies while adding user details.

**like this:**

[image]

And when user add insurance add insurance details, it will show their data in temporary table using jQuery append system

**like this:**

[image]

Now i am facing problem is that, when admin multiple insurance details then it not loop `s. no`. it always shows **1**

**here is my code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                                    function add_ins(){




                                      var mode = $('#Mode').val();
                                      var term = $('#term').val();
                                      var mat_amt = $('#mat_amt').val();
                                      var premium = $('#premium').val();
                                      var ins_date = $('#ins_date').val();

                                      var id = 1;
                                      // alert(mode);

                                      $('#insurance_temp').append('<tr><td>'+id+'</td><td>'+mat_amt+'<input type="text" name="mat_amt[]" value="'+mat_amt+'"><input type="text" name="term[]" value="'+term+'"></td><td>'+ins_date+'<input type="text" name="ins_date[]" value="'+ins_date+'"></td><td>'+mode+'<input type="text" name="Mode[]" value="'+mode+'"></td><td>'+premium+'<input type="text" name="premium[]" value="'+premium+'"></td><td><a style="cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#notification'+id+'"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>&nbsp;Notfication</a></td><td>Edit</td><td>Delete</td></tr>');

                                      id++;

                                      $('#frm_add_insurance')[0].reset();

                                    }
```

i just want to append these records with different serial numbers. please suggest me where i am going wrong

Comment: `$.each($('#insurance_temp tr'), function(){ ... })`

Comment: can you please describe more briefly

Comment: @AshishVyas You can't get much more brief than that.

Comment: You are adding rows dynamically in table, so you can fetch all rows in table and loop over them

Comment: beacuse each time of function call your defining var id = 1; inside the function so it's always 1

Comment: but @JYoThI , i already added i++ after append system. where am i wrong?

Comment: ++ will increment 1 but again the call of function value reset to 1 because your defining the varibale inside the function  var id = 1; so each time of function call value will be reseted to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beacuse each time of function call your defining var id = 1; inside the function so it's always 1

define the variable out side the function globally . so it will go 1..2..3.

Comment: can i ask one more query please?

Comment: yeah ask @AshishVyas

Comment: is their any way, where i can get these dynamically generated id outside this jquery function?

Comment: actually i want to show bootstrap model from these insurance detail row, for user can add their additional details

Comment: variable is defined globally so you can able to access it outside the function too. @AshishVyas

Comment: $('#insurance_temp').append('<tr><td>'+id+'</td><td>'+mat_amt+'<input type="text" name="mat_amt[]" value="'+mat_amt+'"><input type="text" name="term[]" value="'+term+'"></td><td>'+ins_date+'<input type="text" name="ins_date[]" value="'+ins_date+'"></td><td>'+mode+'<input type="text" name="Mode[]" value="'+mode+'"></td><td>'+premium+'<input type="text" name="premium[]" value="'+premium+'"></td><td><a style="cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#notification"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>&nbsp;Notfication</a></td></tr>');
 id++; }

Comment: as you can see above code, hear is my data target named #notification, which is used for call model

Comment: and now out side scrip tag,

i have use id="notification" like this:

</script>
<div class="modal fade" id="notification" role="dialog">

Comment: now, how can i determine to open model with their specific id?

Comment: after append you just open the modal like this $('#notification').modal('show'); @AshishVyas  but id should be unique for each element

Comment: i know it very well that id(s) must be unique for each model, but i'm lil bit confused with their implementation. kindly show me more briefly. your kind effort is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: if you want open the modal manually means you can click  the  notifiction td it will open the modal . @AshishVyas

Comment: here i have change model id inside append tr function, like this:

$('#notification').attr('id','notification'+id);

but it only affected on first tr? why?

Comment: i think you have more duplicate id in name of  #notification  and trying to replace with new id  is it ? @AshishVyas

Comment: can you  list down you modal id's  @AshishVyas

Comment: you need to map  your data-target="#notification1"  to your modal id like this modal id="notification1"  @AshishVyas

Comment: data-toggle="modal" data-target="#notifier'+id+'"> 

$('#notifier').attr('id','notifier'+id);

is that ok?

Comment: i will suggest you . use only one modal with class name class="notifier"   so set all td to data-target=".notifier"  so it will open modal . but you need to access the clicked row values and fill the  modal field with that row values .so it will work generic . getting clicked row values is not that much hard it is simple . we can traverse dom and get all values . @AshishVyas

Comment: OK now its so many comments on this single question for now. 

thanks for your kind support. now i'll fix this issue from own :)

Comment: did you understand my above comment ? .if you understand it will so simple to do . @AshishVyas

Comment: Actually i am totally confused with this models. i search and search on google so many times but the solution is not with me. i'm tired :(

Comment: you can make new question with detailed description of your problem . so people will help you and i too @AshishVyas

Comment: Thanks @JYoThI. 

Here is my new question, you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178335

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting the value of your id to 1 every time it runs your function.  Try initializing your id outside of the function and just increment it within your function.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning id = 1 and that's why you are getting same id all the times. Try This:

```
var id = ($('#insurance_temp tr').length + 1);
```